# Calling a third party API in loopback after saving data

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I have just started with loopback.We are creating a middleware in loopback where a user comes and Fills up a task form. When he submits the form we save the data in our database and then we need to call a third party REST API to store the same data appended with ID which our DB returns.
I read about the REST connector in loopback, but I don't think it serves the purpose. So I decided to go ahead with the request library.
I have created a RemoteMethod where I am doing all this. Here's the code:-

```
const request = require('request');
const url = "http://third-party-api";


module.exports = function(Tasks) {

  function cb(err, data){
    return { data: data };
  }

  Tasks.add = function(data, cb){
    Tasks.create({data: data}, function(err, object){
      var taskId = object.id
      request.get({url: url}, function(error, response, body){
        cb(error, body);
      });
    });
  };

  Tasks.remoteMethod(
        'add',
        {
          accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object'}],
          returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
          http: {path: '/add', verb: "post"}
        }
  );
};
```

But this results in an error(IP changed):-

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","status":500,"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"0.0.0.0"}}
```

I haven't been able to figure out what's going on here. NodeJs, Express, Loopback everything is pretty new to me & I have been going around in circles for quite sometime now.
What am I doing wrong? Is there any other approach that I need to follow

Comment: `connect ECONNREFUSED` means you are not able to communicate with server. may be its issue of port.Check all the required information for communicating the server

Comment: Try to hit your third party API from browser and check it's giving you any information

Comment: The IP coming in the error is not my public IP and even the port coming is not the same as of the loopback server.

Comment: I am able to hit their server from the node console using the request library. The third party API needs basic auth. Won't be able to make call via browser.

Comment: where are you passing the `auth` info while requesting with `request` module

Comment: The loopback REST connector will do exactly what you need. You should use it instead, and if you are starting with loopback, practice a little with the fundamental parts of the framework.

Comment: @abdulbarik I figured it out. Looks like the server which I am calling only responds to https requests. Thanks.

Comment: @Overdrivr How can I save the data to my model in mongodb if I use Rest Connector.

Comment: Well that's already what you are doing when calling `Tasks.create` (given that your model Task is configured in `model-config.json` to be persisted to your mongodb datasource).

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 means all IP on your local machine, localhost.

Most likely, you forgot to define the port on which the external api is listening.

If your external API is listening on port `3001` for instance, then just modify your code like this

```
const url = "http://localhost:3001";
```

Just a note, there is nothing wrong with using `request` for your use case, but the loopback REST connector will also do exactly what you need.